# .NET Git ignore whitespace

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, git

I am using .NET, Visual Studio 2010 and Git in my development at work.
I am looking for a way to make git ignore the white spaces due to different coding styles between our team.

For readability, some of my colleagues really need to have some white spaces while others 
don't.

For example, some of us write code as:

```
var b = new B();
```

While others, write it as:

```
var b = new B( );
```

Since git doesn't understand those white spaces, it threats them as changes. However, that results in some merge conflicts and difficulties to see the actual changes in code.
Is it possible to "make" git understand that this white space should be ignored?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct fix for this would be to make all developers agree up on the same conventions.

And as Jeow Li Huan points out, you can use StyleCop to enforce people actually comply to these conventions.

Comment: And use the tool StyleCop to enforce the conventions http://stylecop.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'd also suggest that you should consider having your team share .vssettings files as well.  This literally gets all your devs on the same page.  Getting them to agree on these settings is an entirely different type of exercise all together.